# How to convert string to multiple variable?

Tags: php, forms, textarea

I would like to create a e-form, the user can input more than one email address on textarea field.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<br><br>    
 <textarea  name="email"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">      
</form>
```

When user type more than one email on the textarea.like the following image
[image]

```
 <?php    

echo $_POST["name"].'<br>';
echo $_POST["email"].'<br>'; //make the three email convert to three variable.
?>
```

any idea do do this???

```
foreach ($_POST["email"] as $email) {
     // anyidea
    }
 $_POST["email"][0] = 'peter@gmail.com';
 $_POST["email"][1] = 'mary@gmail.com';
 $_POST["email"][2] = 'super@yahoo.com';
```

Thank you very much .

Comment: try explode... http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I would do,

```
  $emails = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $_POST['email'])));
```

Explode breaks a string into an array based on the first argument, array_map, works kind of like a loop and applies trim to each element, which trims white space (removes empty spaces from both sides).  Array filter removes any array elements that are falsy.  Such as '' empty strings.

So this takes care of things like

```
 example@email.com, ,,someotheremail@email.com
```

Output

```
array(
   'example@email.com',
   'someotheremail@email.com'
)
```

if you want to be really flexible do this

```
  $emails = array_filter(array_map('trim', preg_split('/(,|\||\s)/', $_POST['email'])))
```

Which does the same as above but lets you use spaces commas or pipes as the delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

You may try splitting your CSV list of emails on the pattern `\s*,\s*`.  This will handle any amount of whitespace coming before or after the comma separators.

```
$input = "peter@gmail.com, mary@gmail.com , super@yahoo.com";
$emails = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $input);
print_r($emails);

Array ( [0] => peter@gmail.com [1] => mary@gmail.com [2] => super@yahoo.com )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode function in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
// Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```